# How to change domain in CGI::Session?

Tags: perl, session, cookies, dns, cgi

I want to use CGI::Session module in order to implement my website sessions.
I want to change session cookie in a way that it will fit to the domain that I want.

For example, I have two sites, `www.mysite.com` and `dev.mysite.com`

In this case I want the session cookie domain to be `mysite.com`.

I've tried to use the module but it only keeps the domain of the script and I want to change it.

Is there a way to do it? Because I looked in the documentation and didn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if you want the cookie to be visible to both `www.mysite.com` and `dev.mysite.com`, the cookies needs to be tied to `.mysite.com`, not `mysite.com`.

On to the question.

```
print $session->header( ... );
```

is documented to be a shortcut for

```
my $cookie = CGI::Cookie->new(
   -name  => $session->name,
   -value => $session->id,
);
print $cgi->header( -cookie => $cookie, ... );
```

So you could use

```
my $cookie = CGI::Cookie->new(
   -name   => $session->name,
   -value  => $session->id,
   -domain => '.mysite.com',
);
print $cgi->header( -cookie => $cookie );
```